# How to Debug cucumber.js features that compiled to Coffe-script in inteliJ

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, coffeescript, cucumberjs

I have tests written in cucumber.js with java script helper classes layer And the code complied to coffee-script.

[image]

The inteliJ can't run the tests 
I tried to configure the Run > Configuration page to run a file watcher

[image]
before the test. (didnt help) 
I need someone how dealt with this problem before please.

Comment: why did you specify a path to  coffeescript executable as a cucumberjs executable path? I believe that the only way to run cucumber tests written in coffeescript in IDEA is pre-compiling them to js first and passing the compiled files to cucumber. Debugging is not yet supported, can be expected in major release next to 2017.3

Comment: Just checked - you don't need to precompile your files, cucmber.js can do this on-the-fly. Just specify a path to cucumber.js executable as *Executable path* in your run configuration

Comment: There is a layer of coffee-script that implement selenium and more so when i configure the executable cucumber.js and run then the compiler dosnt compile the coffee-script and cant recognize all the methods. i tried to do that as InteliJ suggest in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-cucumber-java.html

Comment: Help doesn't suggest specifying coffeescript as cucmber executable; and this will work neither in the IDE nor in terminal - you can't run cucumber tests with coffeescript compiler, you need cucumberjs for this